# Entityframework Core 2.0 Migration will get executed when application runs first time?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to know whether the EF migrations will executed along with seed data without running update-database command? ie. without executing update-database command, i can see all tables created in the database.

Is there any problem or is this the expected behaviour?

I am using separate method to seed data:

```
    public async Task SeedAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //Based on EF team's example at https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs
        using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<WorkflowDBContext>();
            if(!dbContext.AllMigrationsApplied())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<WorkflowDBContext>().Database.Migrate();
                if (!await dbContext.Alert.AnyAsync())
                {
                    await SeedData(dbContext);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static class DbContextExtension
{
    public static bool AllMigrationsApplied(this WorkflowDBContext context)
    {
        var applied = context.GetService<IHistoryRepository>()
                             .GetAppliedMigrations()
                             .Select(m => m.MigrationId);

        var total = context.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()
                             .Migrations
                             .Select(m => m.Key);

        return !total.Except(applied).Any();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EF Core won't ever automatically apply migrations. Your application may be calling `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` or `Migrate()` somewhere...

Comment: thank. i have updated the question and pasted the code i am using to seed data. What i have done is right or any code smell in this?